# Drop lat lon coordinates and index from xarray dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to make the "ts" variable in the following dataset (nds1) have only a time coordinate and I don't want "lat" and "lon" to be indexes, dimensions or coordinates.

[image]

I tried the following:

```
nds1_test1 = nds1.reset_index('lon')
nds1_test1 = nds1_test1.reset_index('lat').reset_coords()
nds1_test1 = nds1_test1.drop_vars('lon_')
nds1_test1 = nds1_test1.drop_vars('lat_')
```

But this still leaves "ts" with lat and lon:

[image]

I did also tried using nds1.drop and nds1.drop_vars but it is not giving me what I need. I would like the data array to just have a coordinate of time (as an index) and the only data variable as "ts". How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’ve tried would work on length-0 dimensions, but you can’t just make a dimension with length >= 1 go away without selecting or reshaping somehow.

Since lat and lon are length 1, the easiest would be [`ds.squeeze`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.squeeze.html), which does exactly what you were trying to do. By default it will convert length-1 dims to length-0; if you want to get rid of them entirely provide `drop=True`, e.g.:

```py
nds1.squeeze(["lat", "lon"], drop=True)
```

You could also achieve this by selecting the data with `.sel` or `.isel`, both of which have `drop` as an optional keyword argument.